# If $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ is p-adic Cauchy, show ord$_p(x_n)$ eventually constant.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Number Theory 1: Fermat's Dream asks the reader to verify the following.  They then use this to extend the definition of Ord$_p$ to $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Let $p$ be prime and $a\neq 0$.

If $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a p-adic Cauchy sequence of rationals whose class is $a \in \mathbb{Q}_p$, show that ord$_p(x_n)$ is constant for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I think you require $a\neq 0$ for this to be true. Maybe the problem really says $\mathbb Q_p^\times$?

Comment: Correct.  I edited that.  Thanks.

Comment: When $a\neq0$, the distance from $x_n$ to $a$ will  eventually fall below $|a|_p$. What does the non-archimedean triangle inequality say about $|x_n|_p=|(x_n-a)+a|_p$ after that point?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060375/96384

Answer (score 2):

I explained in a comment that the other answer makes a false claim about what it means to not converge to $0$. Luckily, one can correct it, as follows:

**Statement**: If a sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy with respect to any [ultrametric value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space) $\lvert \cdot \rvert$, and $x_n$ does not converge to $0$, then there is an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\lvert x_n \rvert = \lvert x_{n+1} \rvert = \lvert x_{n+2} \rvert = \dots$

**Proof**: The sequence not converging to $0$ means there exists a certain $\epsilon_0 >0$ such that for all $k \in \mathbb N$, there is $n \ge k$ with $\lvert x_n \rvert \ge \epsilon_0$.

The sequence being Cauchy means that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $\ell,m \ge N$, we have $\lvert x_\ell -x_m \rvert < \epsilon$.

This applied to $\epsilon = \epsilon_0$ means there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $\ell, m \ge N$, we have $\lvert x_\ell -x_m \rvert < \epsilon_0$. Then the fixed first condition applied to $k :=N$ means there is $n\ge N$ such that, on the one hand, $$\lvert x_n \rvert \ge \epsilon_0, $$ while on the other hand, still $$\lvert x_n - x_m \rvert < \epsilon_0$$ for all $m \ge N$, in particular $m \ge n$. Combined, we have that for all $m \ge n$,

$$\lvert x_n - x_m \rvert < \epsilon_0 \le \lvert x_n \rvert \le \max (\lvert x_n \rvert, \lvert x_m \rvert) .$$

Now we use the *ultra* in ultrametric for the first time: The strong triangle inequality, sharpened to what is sometimes called the "ultrametric maximum principle" or similar, says that

$$\text{ If } \lvert a \rvert \neq \lvert b \rvert \text{ then } \lvert a \pm b \rvert = \max(\lvert a \rvert, \lvert b \rvert)$$

which by contraposition means

$$\text{ If } \lvert a \pm b \rvert < \max(\lvert a \rvert, \lvert b \rvert) \text{ then } \lvert a \rvert =\lvert b \rvert . $$

Apply this to $a = x_n$ and $b =x_m$ for $m = n+1, n+2, n+3, \dots$

Comment: Thank you very much for writing this answer!

Answer (score 0):

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of rational numbers that doesn't converge to zero, then the sequence of valuations, $|x_n|_p$ is constant for sufficiently large $n$.

**Proof**: $(x_n)$ does not tend to zero, so there exists a natural number $N$ and rational $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $|x_n| > \varepsilon$. $(x_n)$ fulfills the Cauchy condition for convergence, so there exists another natural number $N'$ for which the following statement is true: if $n, m \ge N'$ then $|x_n - x_m| < \varepsilon$.

Now set $M$ to be the larger of these two numbers, $N$ and $N'$ and notice, that from $n, m \ge M$ it follows that $|x_n - x_m| < \max(|x_n|, |x_m|)$. Finally the non-archimedean property gives $|x_n| = |x_m|$.

Comment: The first sentence in the proof is actually incorrect. Rather: there exists a (rational) $\varepsilon >0$ such that for all $N$, there exists $n\ge N$ such that $\lvert x_n \rvert >\varepsilon$. That suffices to conclude though, although the rest of the proof needs to be slightly rewritten.