# Limit of non-archimedean absolute values is eventually constant

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in a field $K$ with respect to a non-archimedean absolute value $|\cdot|$ arising from a discrete valuation $v$ (meaning $|x|:=c^{v(x)}$ for some $c\in(0,1)$. Suppose $\operatorname{lim}|x_n|\neq 0$. I'd like to understand why the sequence $(v(x_n))$ becomes evetually constant.

I found this statement at the top of page three in these [notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-785-number-theory-i-fall-2019/lecture-notes/MIT18_785F19_lec8.pdf) by Andrew Sutherland.

The only tool at hand seems to be the non-archimedean triangle inequality, but I'm not sure how to use it. What am I missing?

Comment: OP, are you familiar with uniformizing elements?  When $K$ is $p$-adic, the direct product decomposition $$K^{\ast} \cong \mathbb Z \times \mathcal O_K^{\ast}$$ where $\mathcal O_K^{\ast}$ is the set of elements in $K$ of absolute value $1$ makes the problem much more tractable.

Comment: This is true for any absolute value i.e. group homomorphism $\lvert \cdot \rvert : K^* \rightarrow (\mathbb R^+, \cdot)$ as long as the strong triangle inequality $\lvert x+y \rvert \le \max(\lvert x \rvert, \lvert y \rvert)$ is satisfied, as was explained in an earlier version of @reuns ' answer. We can of course phrase it in terms of an "additive" valuation $v$, but contrary to what D_S seems to believe, that valuation does not need to be discrete.

Comment: The use of the term "non-archimedean" for a norm that induces an ultrametric seems to be to be recipe for endless confusion.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291609/96384

Answer (score 4):

Your questions on $p$-adic numbers are strange, as if to you it was something completely abstract, but $p$-adic numbers are very concrete. If $x\ne 0$ and $x_n\to x$ then $v(x_n-x)>v(x)$ for $n$ large enough so that $v(x_n)=v(x),|x_n|=|x|$. When $K$ is not complete and $(x_n)$ is Cauchy then $x=\lim x_n$ is in its completion instead of $K$ but it doesn't change anything.

$v(x_n-x)>v(x)\implies v(x)=v(x_n)$ is part of the definition:

If $v(x_n) > v(x)$ then $v(x)=v(x_n+(x-x_n))\ge \min(v(x_n),v(x-x_n))$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

When $K$ is a $p$-adic field (rather than just a nonarchimedean field), what you are asking is true, and you have much more tools on hand than just the nonarchimedean inequality.  Let $f: K \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be the function $f(x) = |x|$.

Let $\omega \in K$ be a uniformizer (if $K = \mathbb Q_p$ you can take $\omega = p$), so that $f(\omega) = \rho$ for some $0 < \rho < 1$.  Since every $0 \neq x \in K$ is equal to $u \omega^n$ for a unique integer $n$ and unique $u \in K$ with $|u| = 1$, it is clear that

$$\operatorname{Image}(f) = \{0\} \cup \{..., \rho^2, \rho, 1, \rho^{-1}, \rho^{-2}, ... \}$$

Now if $\{x_n\} \in K$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a convergent sequence in $\operatorname{Image}(f)$.  If we assume that $\{x_n\}$ does not converge to $0$, then $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a convergent sequence in

$$\{..., \rho^2, \rho, 1, \rho^{-1}, \rho^{-2}, ... \}.$$

This last set being discrete (every singleton set is open), the only convergent sequences therein are those which are eventually constant.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer finding "the trick" so yes clearly it works for every non-archimedean valuation. @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: To be clear: I agree with @reuns that all we need is the strong triangle inequality. Using discreteness of the valuation, as you do, is overkill (or to put it nicer: it gives another argument for sure, but obfuscates that the statement indeed holds e.g. vor $\mathbb C_p$, contrary to what you claim).

Comment: You are right, I have edited