# Possible norms of elements in $\mathbb{C}_{p}$

Tags: normed-spaces, p-adic-number-theory, formal-completions

Let $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ be the $p$-adic field, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}$ be its algebraic closure and $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ the completion of the latter. There is a unique well defined norm $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ that extends the $p$-adic norm on $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. I am interested in the possible values of this norm.

It is obvious that the possible values of this norm on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}$ are fractional powers of $p$ - this is just clear from the definition. In Neil Koblitz’s book “p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions”, the author claims that the same is true for $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}$, but leaves the proof as an exercise.

For me this is not easy to see, since the set of fractional powers of $p$ is obviously dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so a-priori it seems that any positive real number can be a possible value of the norm.

My main idea is to somehow use Krasner’s Lemma to show that if $\{x_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy-sequence in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}$, then there must be a subsequence that is contained in a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$, but I can’t seem to achieve this…

Is this fact true? Are the possible values of the norm of elements of $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ only fractional powers of $p$? How can one prove this? Any hints or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a standard exercise in ultrametrics: Let $K, \lvert \cdot \rvert$ be any field with an ultrametric absolute value. Use the ultrametric property to show: If $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the field which does *not* converge to $0$, then the sequence of values $\lvert x_n \rvert$ is eventually constant. (Do this exercise yourself. For proofs on this site, cf. [Limit of non-archimedean absolute values is eventually constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060375/96384) and [If $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ is p-adic Cauchy, show ord$_p(x_n)$ eventually constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291609/96384) .)

Now, by definition, every element of $\mathbb C_p$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence of elements in $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$.

Comment: Ok, I am a silly man, thanks for pointing this argument to me. I knew this for (say) $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ but I just argued that the possible values of the norm is a discrete set, didn't notice your argument, which is better (because it always works).