# A proof of a basic result regrading Cauchy sequence in p-adic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

This question was left as an exercise in a seminar of p-adic integers.

The issue is that I have not studied any algebraic number theory and hence I am not able to think about how to prove  this particular result. But I want to learn basics of p-adic number theory and hence want to know how to solve this particular problem.

> Question:  In $\mathbb{Q}_p$ , show that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy sequence iff $|x_{n+1} - x_{n}|_p \to 0$.

I found a solution here:[If $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ is p-adic Cauchy, show ord$_p(x_n)$ eventually constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291609/if-x-n-n-geq-1-x-n-in-mathbbq-is-p-adic-cauchy-show-ord-px-n-e)

But in the answer I am having these questions and the OP of question is not seen since atleast 1 month ago and OP of answer has deleted the account:

Assuming $  (x_n)$ is cauchy , then in the answer I have question that :(i) why can't the sequence $(x_n)$converge to 0?

(ii) what is non-acrhemedian property and how does it implies that $|x_m|= |x_n|$? Rest of the answer is clear to me.

Conversly, I am not able to prove that $(x_n)$ is cauchy assuming that $|x_{n+1} - x_{n}|_p| \to 0$ ?

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: In the question you link, and in its answer, it is explicitly *assumed* that the sequence does *not converge to zero*. Of course there exist sequences that go to $0$, and for them the conclusion need not hold. E.g. $x_n=p^n$. That should settle (i).

Comment: $|x_n-x_{n+k}|_p \le \sup_{i< k} |x_{n+i}-x_{n+i+1}|_p$ that's the main difference between sequences of real numbers and sequences of $p$-adic numbers. So it is immediate that $|x_{n+1} - x_{n}|_p \to 0$ implies $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. The converse is obvious as well.

Comment: For (ii), by "non-archimedean property" they mean the [strong triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space#Formal_definition) and/or its sharpening, as alluded to in reuns' comment. Note also that it is not necessary to know any algebraic number theory for this, just basics of metrics.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg So, how does it implies that $|x_m|= |x_n|?$

Comment: @3ibfwcbi: I have posted an answer to the linked question, since I realized the existing answer was imprecise. In my answer, I try to make the last step, where one uses that "non-archimedean (maximum) property", as clear as I possibly can. The upshot is that for ultrametric / non-arch. values, $\lvert a-b \rvert < \lvert a \rvert$ (or $< \lvert b \rvert$) necessarily implies $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert b \rvert$. ("If points are close to each other, they must have the same valuation".)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you very much!

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Can you please help me with the converse part as well?

Comment: @reuns Can you prove the assertion you mentioned in the 1st line of your answer?

Comment: Which one? Do you know that $|a+b|\le \max(|a|,|b|)$ ?

Comment: The converse part follows from reuns' statement which follows from a telescoping argument (say $n \ge m+1$, then $x_n-x_m = (x_n-x_{n-1}) + (x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}) + \dots + (x_{m+1}-x_m)$) and the obvious generalization of $\lvert a+b \rvert \le \max(\lvert a\rvert, \lvert b \rvert)$ to more than two summands.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you very much!